# How to use Broadcast variable correctly in Spark GraphX?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I use GraphX for processing a graph. i have used GraphLoader to load it and i made a variable that contains the neighbors of each node by using below code:

```
val all_neighbors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).cache()
```

because i frequently need nodes neighbors i decide to broadcast them. when i use this code i get error:

```
val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(all_neighbors)
```

but when i use this code there is no error:

```
val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(all_neighbors.collect())
```

is it right to use collect() for broadcasting??

and one more question. i want to change this broadcast variable to be key,value. is this code right?

```
val nvalues = broadcastVar.value.toMap
```

does the above code(i means nvalues) broadcast to all slaves in cluster?? should i broadcast nvalues too?? i am a little bit confused with broad cast subject. please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions:

> is it right to use collect() for broadcasting??

`all_neighbors` is of type VertexRDD which is essentially an RDD. There is nothing in an RDD you could broadcast. [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) is a data structure that describes a distributed computation on some datasets. By the features of RDD, you can describe what and how to compute. It's an abstract entity. You can only broadcast a real value, but an RDD is just a container of values that are only available when executors process their data.

quoting from [Broadcast Variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables):

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable
>   cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.
>   They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large
>   input dataset in an efficient manner.
>
> This means that explicitly creating broadcast variables is only useful
>   when tasks across multiple stages need the same data or when caching
>   the data in deserialized form is important.

That's the reason we need to perform `collect` the dataset that RDD holds which converts the RDD to a locally-available collection which can then be broadcasted.

Note: When you perform `collect` operation, data is accumulated in the driver node and then broadcasted. So if space in the driver node is less, it will throw errors

> does the above code(i means nvalues) broadcast to all slaves in
>   cluster?? should I broadcast nvalues too??

It totally depends on your use case. If you want to only use `broadcastVar`, then only broadcast it or if you want to use `nvalues`, only broadcast `nvalues` or else you can broadcast both the values though you need to be careful of memory constraints.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: thank you some much for your complete descriptions. it was so helpful for me. thank you.

Comment: If it helped, pls upvote and close this answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i have another question that has same subject with this question i asked. can you please have a look at that question? this is the link for that. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493554/comparing-intersection-between-two-nodes-using-broadcast-variable-and-using-rdd)